# How to format number 1 to string "01" for aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create aggregation keys in the form of "YYYYMMDD" based on a date field within my documents. Using the `$month` and `$dayOfMonth` operators however, I only get numbers returned, without a means of formatting them to leading zeros (and in addition, I can't concatenate numbers).

I'd prefer aggregation over Map/Reduce, due to the blocking nature of the latter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You basically use the [**`$concat`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator to join the strings with a few conditions, as well as [**`$substr`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to handle the conversions:

```js
"day": { 
    "$concat": [
        { "$substr": [ { "$year": "$date" }, 0, 4  ] },
        { "$cond": [
            { "$lte": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 9 ] },
            { "$concat": [
                "0", { "$substr": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] }
            ]},
            { "$substr": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] }
        ]},
        { "$cond": [
            { "$lte": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, 9 ] },
            { "$concat": [
                "0", { "$substr": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] }
            ]},
            { "$substr": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, 0, 2 ] }
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Another approach if you are aggregating by "day" is to just use a "epoch" value with date math:

```js
"day": {
    "$subtract": [
        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
        { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Any date math operation on two date objects results in the epoch milliseconds as a difference. So use the epoch date as a date object in order to convert. The resulting value is the "day" for the timestamp value, and can be fed back to create a date object when processing your results.

Arguably you could do the same thing in post processing with the [**`$year`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) and [**`$dayOfYear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/) results, as those would also be enough to re-constitute a date object in client processing

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome and horrible at the same time. So $substr automatically casts a number to a string, but $concat doesn't. Room for improvement here.

Comment: @Marian Yes. nasty and horrible thing that keep threatening to be unsupported. Why really I am not sure. But really try to look at other methods of getting your "date" formatted in the way you want in your final result. Post processing is a better way to go.

Comment: I had a multi-part key first, but sorting by it's parts didn't turn out the way I expected. Now it works fine. Let's see how long it lasts.

Answer (score 11):

While Neil's answer does work, I felt it was rather unsatisfactory; it's hard to read, hard to maintain, and slow. Assuming you're getting the value from a date (as was mentioned in the OP); if you're on mongo 3.0 or later, using [$dateToString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString) is the best way, but if you're stuck on an earlier version (like me) I think you're better off simply reading the portion of the string you want from the date field (as these are zero-padded):

```
formattedTime: {
    $concat: [
        { $substr: ["$timestamp", 0, 4] },
        { $substr: ["$timestamp", 5, 2] },
        { $substr: ["$timestamp", 8, 2] }
    ]
}
```

This works especially well in my case where I just wanted to get `<hours>:<minutes>` (which is a right pain using @Neil's solution since I want to zero pad two numbers), but this way becomes simply: `formattedTime: { $substr: [ "$timestamp", 11, 5 ] }`

Of course, I recommend replacing the magic numbers with some named constants for improved readability.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for recent MongoDB versions: It is a clean and brief solution.